# Wondering what the word "receiving" here means

Tags: word-meaning

> Since last September Aleppo, Syria's largest city and its former economic capital, has been at the **receiving end** of what the pressure group Human Rights Watch (HRW) calls "an indiscriminate and unlawful air war against civilians by the Syrian government". Last month HRW produced a study into the scale of the attacks.

-It is difficult to me figuring out what the meaning of **the city has been at the receiving end of an unlawful war**, really means. 
Receiving? I would appreciate your help, providing some similar examples.

Comment: The term may have a positive connotation too: God is the Giver and humankind is the receiver.

Answer (score 4):

Being at the receiving end of something means that someone does something to you, and you receive it.

If I hit you, you are at the receiving end of that blow.

Answer (score 0):

Syrian government was at the giving end while the city of Aleppo (and its inhabitants) was at the receiving end of “an indiscriminate and unlawful air war”.